# How to get the ddl of the views in sqlite?

Tags: java, sql, database, sqlite, jdbc

I need to build the structure of a database. I can get the names of views using `databasemetadata.getTables(null,null,"%","VIEWS");`

but how to get the ddl, that is, the query of the view ?

Comment: `select sql from sqlite_schema where type = 'view'`

Comment: Thank you. And I also wonder if I can get it through jdbc metadata instead of schema table?

Answer (score 0):

There are 10 columns returned in the resultset of `databasemetadata.getTables()`, but none of them contains the definition of the views.

What you can do is query the table `sqlite_master` and get 2 columns: `name` and `sql` which correspond to the name of the view and its definition:

```
String select_views = "SELECT name, sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'view';";
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(); // conn is the connection object
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(select_views);
while (rs.next()) {
   System.out.println(rs.getString("name") + "\t" + rs.getString("sql"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  And I also wonder if I can get it through jdbc metadata instead of schema table?

Comment: Does that totally means I cannot get the ddl through metadata ?   Anyway, your answer of sqlite_master have solved my problem and I was just wondering if there exists another method.

Comment: @oxyuranus No, the ddl is not contained in the resultset of databasemetadata.getTables().